# run a trigger in an interval time in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

Is possible triggering a function in postgres at a timed interval??

For example

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteOldRecords BEFORE "TIME_OUT" ON table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE deleteOldRecordsP();
```

Comment: See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237283/postgresql-everyday-trigger

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scheduled database jobs for PostgreSQL are usually done by `cron` or [pg_agent](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/pgagent.html). The [CREATE TRIGGER statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtrigger.html) doesn't support timed intervals as a type of event.

Comment: ohh, i am stoned. i need it,